# error en localhost phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

cuando quiero ingresar a http://localhost/phpmyadmin/,me sale este error y no sé como solucionarlo

> Fatal error: Call to a member function exists() on null in
>   C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php on line
>   1544

y ni siquiera he creado una base,ya que no logro entrar

Comment: Esa URL es correcta? es decir debe finalizar en /,me? con el uso de coma?

Comment: Hay algo que se pregunto similar que se pregunto espero ayudar: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50121660/fatal-error-uncaught-error-call-to-a-member-function-exists-on-null-in-c-xa]

Comment: Te puede servir este [Hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50121660/fatal-error-uncaught-error-call-to-a-member-function-exists-on-null-in-c-xa)

Comment: es extraña tu url..generalmente es: http://localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: no...http://localhost/phpmyadmin/,me

Comment: El `me` que aparece en su url me imagino que ha sido un error de escritura aquí en la pregunta nada más, no que lo esté escribiendo así en su contexto.